# Combinatorial proof for Stirling number of 1st kind's generating function

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

So I see this identity a lot but I can't find a detailed combinatorial proof for it. 
$$n(n+1)...(n+k-1)=\sum_{j=0}^k \begin{bmatrix}k \\j \end{bmatrix}n^j$$
Can someone please help?

Comment: And see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850080/using-combinatorics-to-show-that-x-overline-n-sum-k-0n-n-brack-kxk/3851757#3851757) for a slightly different combinatorial argument that also justifies replacing $n$ with an arbitrary real number $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sides are counted by the number of ways to place $k$ distinct flags on $n$ distinct flagpoles, where the order in which several flags are stacked matters.

#### Left Hand Side

The first flag can be placed on any of $n$ poles. The second can be placed on the bottom of any pole, or on top of the first, for $n+1$ options. Continuing, the $i^{th}$ flag can be placed in any of $n+i-1$ places, either on the bottom of any pole, or just above any of the $i-1$ previously placed flags. Therefore, the number of possibilities is $\prod_{i=1}^n(n+i-1)$.

#### Right Hand Side

This is the trickier construction. Assume the $k$ flags are numbered $1$ to $k$. Here is a procedure for choosing a flag placement, which I claim uniquely represents every placement:

1. Choose an integer $j$ between $0$ and $k$.
2. Choose a permutation of the flags with exactly $j$ cycles. Write this permutation in cycle notation so that each cycle has its smallest element first, and so the initial elements of the cycles *decrease* from left to right.
3. Proceeding from left to right, choose a pole for each cycle, and place the flags in that cycle on the pole, preserving their order as written.

For example, say $k=9$ and $n=3$. We choose $j=4$, and choose the permutation

$$\pi=(5\,9)(3\, 4)(2)(1\, 8\, 6\, 7).$$

We then choose to put the (5 9) on the left pole, (3 4) on the right pole, (2) on the right pole, and (1 8 6 7) on the right pole, resulting in

```
|   |   7
|   |   6
|   |   8
|   |   1
|   |   2
9   |   4
5   |   3
```

The reason the cycles can be uniquely recovered is because each one begins with a number that is smaller than all numbers below it. For example, the 2 is smaller than 4 and 3, so it must begin a cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful