# Rising Factorial and Stirling number of the 1st kind

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

Is it true that

$$(x+1)^{\bar{n}}=  \sum_{k \ge 0} \sum
_{i=0}^{n} {i \choose k}s_{n,i}\,\,x^k  \,\,\,\,?$$  where $s_{n,i}$ is the Stirling number of the first kind and the $\bar{n}$ denote rising factorial. If yes, could anyone please show me?

I have been able to prove that
$$(x+1)^{\bar{n}}=  \sum_{k \ge 0} s_{n+1,k+1}\,\,x^k  \,\,\,\,$$

My goal is to try to get that $$s_{n+1,k+1} = \sum
_{i=0}^{n} {i \choose k}s_{n,i}$$ by equating (comparing) both identities

Comment: Obviously you can change the lower bound of $i$ to $k$, because when $i < k$ the binomial coefficient is zero. Wikipedia's page on Stirling numbers of the first kind includes:

The identity $$\sum _{p=k}^{n}{\left[{n \atop p}\right]{\binom {p}{k}}}=\left[{n+1 \atop k+1}\right]$$ can be proved by the techniques on the page [Stirling numbers and exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_and_exponential_generating_functions_in_symbolic_combinatorics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with the identity
$$
x^{\overline n} = \sum_{i=0}^n s_{n,i}x^i?\tag{$*$}
$$
The desired result follows pretty quickly substituting $x+1$ for $x$ in $(*)$:
$$
(x+1)^{\overline n}=\sum_{i=0}^n s_{n,i}(x+1)^i = \sum_{i=0}^ns_{n,i}\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{i}kx^k.
$$
Identity $(*)$ can be proved by induction on $n$ using the relation $s_{n+1,k}=s_{n,k-1}+ns_{n,k}$, combined with $x^{\overline{n+1}}=x\cdot x^{\overline n}+nx^{\overline n}$. There is also a [combinatorial proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2704143/177399).

Comment: Oh my God. I am so stupid. I used that identity to proved the first part that I claimed. Yes I see what you mean. I was  not thinking in that way at all. Thanks.

Comment: @Jaynot Well, that's the thing with combinatorics, there often is not an obviously right way to attack a problem, so just because a short proof exist does not mean you should beat yourself up for not being able to find it!

Answer (score 0):

For the identity

$$\sum_{p=k}^n {n\brack p} {p\choose k}
= {n+1\brack k+1}$$

we obtain on the LHS using formal power series

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{p=k}^n {p\choose k}
\frac{1}{p!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^p$$

We have $\log\frac{1}{1-z} = z + \cdots$ so there is no contribution
to the coefficient extractor when $p\gt n$ and we may continue with

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{p\ge k} {p\choose k}
\frac{1}{p!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^p
\\ = n! [z^n] \sum_{p\ge 0} {p+k\choose k}
\frac{1}{(p+k)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{p+k}
\\ = n! [z^n] \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k}
\sum_{p\ge 0} {p+k\choose k}
\frac{1}{(p+k)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{p}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k}
\sum_{p\ge 0} \frac{1}{p!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{p}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k}
\exp\log\frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = n! [z^n]
\frac{1}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k}
 \frac{1}{1-z}.$$

For the RHS we start from

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n\brack k+1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k+1}$$

so that by differentiation

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+1\brack k+1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \frac{1}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k}
\frac{1}{1-z}.$$

We see that the LHS and the RHS  have the same EGF and this proves the
claim. Here  we have  made repeated use  of the  labeled combinatorial
class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times \textsc{CYC}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This  is  the decomposition  of  permutations  into sets  of  disjoint
cycles.

Comment: Thank you also Marko.!