# Combinatorial proof for Stirling number of 1st kind

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers, permutation-cycles

This question is duplicate. But I have some questions about the already posted answers. And temporarily I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I post one new question. Sorry for that.

This [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162164/1059606) may need some knowledge with group which I currently haven't learnt.

1. For $n(n+1)...(n+k-1)=\sum_{j=0}^k \begin{bmatrix}k \\j \end{bmatrix}n^j$, I followed [answer_1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2704143/1059606).

   > Both sides are counted by the number of ways to place $k$ distinct flags on $n$ distinct flagpoles, where the order in which several flags are stacked matters.
   >
   > #### Left Hand Side
   >
   > The first flag can be placed on any of $n$ poles. The second can be placed on the bottom of any pole, or on top of the first, for $n+1$ options. Continuing, the $i^{th}$ flag can be placed in any of $n+i-1$ places, either on the bottom of any pole, or just above any of the $i-1$ previously placed flags. Therefore, the number of possibilities is $\prod_{i=1}^n(n+i-1)$.
   >
   > #### Right Hand Side
   >
   > ...
   >
   > For example, say $n=9$ and $k=3$. We choose $j=4$, and choose the permutation
   > $$\pi=(5\,9)(3\, 4)(2)(1\, 8\, 6\, 7).$$
   > We then choose to put the (5 9) on the left pole, (3 4) on the right pole, (2) on the right pole, and (1 8 6 7) on the right pole, resulting in
   >
   > ```
   >    |   |   7
   >    |   |   6
   >    |   |   8
   >    |   |   1
   >    |   |   2
   >    9   |   4
   >    5   |   3
   > ```

   For the above offered example, I thought it first choose $4$ cycles (although the above may be mistaken to let $k=3<j$), so $\begin{bmatrix}k \\4 \end{bmatrix}$. Then it assigns one of $n$ poles to each cycle, so $n^j$. Then based on the product rule, we have the factor $\begin{bmatrix}k \\4 \end{bmatrix} n^j$.

   But **the cycle order** implies $(1\, 8\, 6\, 7)$ is same as $(8\, 6\, 7\, 1)$ while it is not this case in the Left Hand Side. Then how does the two sides become same?
2. For generalized version for real number $x$, $(x)_n \equiv x(x-1)\cdots (x-(n-1)) = \sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k) x^k$.

   This [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704111/combinatorial-proof-for-stirling-number-of-1st-kinds-generating-function/2704143#comment7952106_2704111) unluckily lost its link.

   - Then I tried this [answer_2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4349892/1059606).

     > Imagine the process of expanding this product from the left. We record which summand (from the left) we choose on the $k$th term $\left(x+\underset{n-k\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1+\dots+1}}\right)$. Say that you chose the $i_k$th summand from the $k$th term. We define a sequence $j_1,\dots,j_n$ by
     > $$j_{k+1}=i_{k+1}\text{th smallest element in }\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{j_1,\dots,j_{k}\}.$$
     > The sequence $j_1\dots j_{n}$ is a reordering of $1,\dots ,n$. Now for each $k$ such that $i_k=1,$ put a slash "/" between $j_{k}$ and $j_{k+1}.$ This means that if you chose $i$ $x$'s, then you have $i$ slashes. The resulting sequence looks like
     > $$j_1\dots j_{k_{1}}/j_{k_1+1}\dots j_{k_2}/\dots/j_{k_{i}+1}\dots j_{n},$$
     > and we can regard this sequence as a permutation which is the product of $i$ cycles.

     The above construction of $j_i$ is a bit complex. I was still stuck with **the cycle order**. Why can $j_1\dots j_{k_{1}}$ be thought same as $j_{k_{1}} j_1 j_2 \dots j_{k_{1}-1}$. Since this cyclic reorder is dependent on $i_k$ and each $j_i$ is dependent on $j_t,t<i$, it seems to be nontrivial to show this cyclic reorder doesn't influence the result.
   - I also tried [answer_3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3878213/1059606) which is similar to [answer_1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2704143/1059606).

     > On the other hand, consider the following method of choosing a permutation, $\pi$. You first choose $\pi(1)$, from one of $n$ options. Then, you choose $\pi(\pi(1))$, then $\pi(\pi(\pi(1)))$, and so on until you complete a cycle. Then, you choose $\pi(s)$, where $s$ is the smallest unassigned element, etc. During the $k^{th}$ stage of this process, you have $n-k+1$ options. Exactly one of these leads to the creation of a cycle.
     > After some thought, these processes are exactly the same, so that the number of ways to choose a permutation with $k$ cycles is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $x^{\overline n}$.

     What does $\pi(1)$ mean? If it means that we choose the $\pi(1)$th item in the 1st factor $x+n-1$, then the cycle $\pi(\pi(\ldots\pi(s))),s\neq 1$ will **not choose the 1st item $x$** of each factor in the permutation process. Then how does the above whole process imply "the coefficient of $x^k$"?

Q:

The above shows the somewhat hard tries by me to understand the relation between **cycle** implied by the Stirling number of 1st kind and the rising factorial. Could someone help with one of the above questions or offer one easier explanation? Thanks beforehand.

**Edit**:

During my spare time, I rethought about the above tried answers based on the following transcribed Brian M. Scott's answer and understood them. Thanks very much.

1. answer_1 which is based on two counting methods of one same object:

   This one is very similar to the following transcribed Brian M. Scott's answer because they both includes 2 steps where one is for $\begin{bmatrix}k \\j \end{bmatrix}$ and one is for $n^j$.

   After thinking about the **canonical cycle representation** (**uniquely** defining the product of cycles) which corresponds to the step 2 of RHS and

   > because each one begins with a number that is smaller than **all** numbers **below** it

   .Then the above $(8\, 6\, 7\, 1)$ is impossible here (sorry for making such a low-level error in the above). It should be $(8)(6\, 7)(1)$.
2. answer_2

   - It "contains exactly the same information" as answer_3 which is said by the answer_2's author. Here I explains how they are same which is not understood when I read it without understanding Brian M. Scott's answer.

     Here each cycle $j_{k_i+1}\dots j_{k_{i+1}}$ implies **ending with the smallest** (similar to [canonical cycle representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Canonical_cycle_notation) which **starts with the largest**) element in $\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{j_1,\dots,j_{k_1},\dots,j_{k_2},\dots,j_{k_i}\}$ since $i_{k_{i+1}}=1$. So it is **impossible** for something like  $j_{k_{1}} j_1 j_2 \dots j_{k_{1}-1}$ to occur which implies it can be thought as one cycle.

     Also $j_{k_1}<j_{k_2}<\ldots<j_{k_i},i\ge 2$ which is also similar to canonical cycle representation.

     Then its process is something like:

     1. Rearrange $j_1,\dots,j_{k_1}$ corresponding the original increasing sub-sequence like $1,\ldots,m_{k_1}$ so that $j_{k_1}=1$. This corresponds to $\pi(\pi(\pi(\dots\pi(1))))=1$
     2. Rearrange $j_{k_1+1}\dots j_{k_2}$ corresponding the original increasing sub-sequence like $s,\ldots,m_{k_2}$ so that $j_{k_2}=s$. This corresponds to $\pi(\pi(\pi(\dots\pi(s))))=s$. This is due to the choice of $s$:

        > Then, you choose $\pi(s)$, where $s$ is the **smallest** unassigned element, etc.

        .The rest is similar.

     Then the example offered by answer_2 means that $\pi(1)=3,\pi(\pi(1))=1;\pi(2)=4,\pi(\pi(2))=2$.
   - Based on the canonical cycle representation, it is similar to answer_1.
3. answer_3 which is based on two counting methods of one same object where the construction of one cycle corresponds to one choice of $x$ among $x+1+\dots+1$:

   > **Exactly one** of these leads to the creation of a cycle.

   It corresponds to that exactly one of $(x+1+\dots+1)$ contributes to $x$ factor in $x^k$.

   So if $s\neq 1$ is the start of one cycle, then $\pi(\pi(\pi(\dots\pi(s))))=s$ (here we use the [product/composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition) operation) means that it chooses one $x$ factor because **only** $s$ among all available choices at each permutation step can cause the construction of the cycle although $s\neq 1$.

   More specifically, here $\pi(s)$ doesn't choose among $x+1+\dots+1$. It chooses among left unchosen elements among $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

   The above is mostly same as the original answer_3 author says. But I add some emphasizes related with my questions above.

Comment: I was the one who wrote the flagpole answer. You correctly noticed that I had a mistake in my answer. I mixed up $k$ and $n$ originally, and this is now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that there was an [answer which lost its link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850080/using-combinatorics-to-show-that-x-overline-n-sum-k-0n-n-brack-kxk/3851757#3851757). Actually, the question and answer still exist, but only users with a high enough reputation can view them. Since it may be helpful to you, I have transcribed the deleted question and answer below.

#### Question (user801358)

> Using combinatorics to show that $$x^{\overline n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\brack k}x^k$$
>
> Where $x^{\overline n}$ is defined as
> $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(x+i\right)$ and ${ n\brack k}$ denotes
> [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).
>
> The left-hand side counts the number of injections from $[n]$ to $[x+n-1]$, however, I don't know what the right-hand side
> does count and why these two are the same.
>
> I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{ n\brack k}=\left|S_n\right|$,but I don't
> know if that helps.( $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $[n]$)

#### Answer (Brian M. Scott)

> Because both sides are polynomials in $x$, it suffices to prove the
> identity for positive integers $x$: the polynomials are of degree $n$,
> so if they agree at more than $n$ values of $x$, they must be
> identical. Fix $m\in\Bbb Z^+$.
>
> Suppose that $1\le k\le n$, and let $S_n(k)$ be the set of
> permutations of $[n]$ with $k$ cycles. For each
> $\pi=\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_k\in S_n(k)$ and
> $\langle\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k\rangle\in[m]^k$, give each element of the
> cycle $\sigma_i$ the label $\ell_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$; this produces
>
> $$\left|S_n(k)\times[m]^k\right|={n\brack k}m^k$$
>
> labelled permutations. Summing over $k$ yields the number of
> permutations of $[n]$ whose elements are labelled with members of some
> subset of $[m]$ in such a way that all of the elements in any cycle
> have the same label.
>
> We can also count those labelled permutations as follows. Let $\tau$
> be any sequence of length $n+m-1$ whose elements are the integers in
> $[n]$ and $m-1$ identical markers; a straightforward stars-and-bars
> argument shows that there are $n!\binom{n+m-1}n$ such sequences. I
> claim that there is a bijection between these sequences and the
> labelled permutations of the previous paragraph. Let $\pi$ be the
> permutation of $[n]$ obtained by deleting the markers from $\tau$. The
> markers divide $\pi$ into $m$ segments, any of which can be empty.
> If $\rho=\langle r_1,\ldots,r_k\rangle$ is a non-empty segments, we
> can regard it as the [canonical cycle
> representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Canonical_cycle_notation_(a.k.a._standard_form))
> of a permutation of $\{r_1,\ldots,r_k\}$. Let $\pi'$ be the product of
> the cycles derived in this way from the non-empty segments. Finally,
> if $\sigma$ is one of the cycles of $\pi'$, and $\sigma$ was derived
> from the $i$-th segment, empty or non-empty, of $\tau$, we give every
> element of $\pi'$ the label $i$. Clearly $\pi'$ is one of the labelled
> permutations of the previous paragraph, and it’s not hard to see that
> every one of those labelled permutations can be produced in this way.
> It follows that
>
> $$m^{\overline{n}}=n!\binom{n+m-1}n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\brack k}m^k$$
>
> for all $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ and hence that
>
> $$x^{\overline{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\brack k}x^k.$$

Comment: Sorry. My original confusion about the cycle order is still there after viewing this answer. Here is my understanding of this answer: $n!$ in $n!\binom{n+m-1}n$ implies that $12|34|\ast\ldots$ is different from $21|34|\ast\ldots$ (here I use the "stars-and-bars" notation). Then how does it ensure the bijection to ["canonical cycle representation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Canonical_cycle_notation) where "in each cycle the **largest** element is listed **first**". Could you help with this obstacle when understanding the relation? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: After some more re-thoughts during my spare time, I think I understand the problem now. $n!\binom{n+m-1}n$ first chooses $n$ locations for $n$ numbers among $[n]$, and then order them which may result in **both increasing and decreasing** sub-orders. Let us choose one arbitrary permutation containing both kinds of orders, e.g. $\overbrace{||\ldots|}^{m-2\;|s}12|34\;n\;n-1\;\ldots 5$.

Comment: Then the above corresponds to ${n\brack 5}*m^5$ where it becomes $\overbrace{||\ldots|}^{m-2\;|s}1\vdots 2|3\vdots 4\vdots\;n\;n-1\;\ldots 5$ (Here I use $\vdots$ to split between cycles which belong to **the same segment**). This process can always generate cycles in the sequence like $\overbrace{||\ldots|}^{m-2\;|s}12|34\;n\;n-1\;\ldots 5$ based on the "canonical cycle representation", then implying the **onto** relation from "the labelled permutations" to "these sequences".

Comment: Since the decreasing subsequence set $S$ decides the contents of cycles and the bar location choice $c$ decide which segment each cycle belongs to, then each $(S,c)$ has one **unique** "labelled permutation" to be mapped to it. For each sequence in "these sequences", there is also only one **unique** $(S,c)$ to be mapped to it. So each sequence in "these sequences" has one **unique** "labelled permutation" to be mapped to it, implying **one-to-one** relation from "the labelled permutations" to "these sequences". Thanks very much for this posted answer.

Comment: When I doing some homework later, I found the above one-to-one correspondence can be also proven by that the function $f$ which adds $\vdots$ to the sequence has one inverse function $f^{-1}$ which removes correspondingly (The one-to-one correspondence is learnt some time before, and not all possible proof paths are tried when I wrote the above comments). The above and this comments are based on my understanding of the posted answer. Please point out errors if any. Thanks beforehand.